# Sum over defined period of time in months

Tags: mysql

Got a good one here... 
I currently have the following bit of code that basically sums the total of active accounts by month.
That is simple, however what I'm wanting to do the same thing on a per category basis and over a defined period and not just one month Ie. over 12 months.... Any ideas / assistance please....My brain is flat :(

```
   SELECT
DATE_FORMAT(s.`DateCreated`,'%Y-%M') AS `Date Created`
, DATE_FORMAT(s.`DateEnd`,'%Y-%M') AS `Date End`
,(@csum := @csum + COUNT(DISTINCT(acc.`AccountId`))) AS Active
FROM (SELECT @csum := 0) AS csums, xx_accountdetails acc
INNER JOIN xx_services s USING(accountid)
LEFT JOIN xx_category cat ON(CategoryId)

INNER JOIN xx_products prod USING(productid)
LEFT JOIN xx_subcategory sc ON(prod.Subcategoryid = sc.SubCategoryId)
LEFT JOIN xx_invoiceline il USING(serviceid)
LEFT JOIN xx_invoices i USING(invoiceid)


WHERE DATE_FORMAT(s.DateStart,'%Y-%m') <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
AND
s.`ProductId` NOT IN (4001,4002)

AND cat.`CategoryId` = '1'

AND
(DATE_FORMAT(s.`DateEnd`,'%Y-%m') >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
OR
(s.`DateEnd` IS NULL
AND s.`IsActive` = 1
AND (s.`SuspendReasonId` != 3 OR s.`SuspendReasonId` IS NULL)))

GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(s.DateCreated,'%Y-%m')
```

Comment: Can you define your table structure properly here? and out put you want

Comment: Basically all I'm wanting to do is result an active count per month of a period of lets say 12 month.... The above works when I define WHERE DATE_FORMAT(s.DateEnd,'%Y-%m') = '2013-10' however I want to define the period for a 12 month range

Comment: `where
    s.DateEnd > (current_date - INTERVAL '12 months')` is working?

Comment: Consider to provide sample data and desired output

Comment: Agree @peterm completly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the date range, simply change the date intervals, e.g.:

```
date_sub(now(), interval 12 months)
```

For the per categories, you need to add an extra group by statement:

```
group by cat.CategoryId, ...
```

Remove the where clause on it, too, else you'll only have `CategoryId = 1`.